# provide user defined value to scheduler at run time

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have create xml file for scheduler but i am unable to do run time customization code.

below is my xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="runMeTask" class="com.spring.server.tasks.ShareMeTask" />

    <bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.spring.server.job.ShareMeJob" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="* 0/10 * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <!-- <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="runMeJob" />
            </list>
        </property>
 -->
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

.

```
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

import com.spring.server.tasks.ShareMeTask;

public class ShareMeJob extends QuartzJobBean {
    private ShareMeTask shareMeTask;

    public void setRunMeTask(ShareMeTask shareMeTask) {
        this.shareMeTask = shareMeTask;
    }

    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("ShareMeJob");
        shareMeTask.printMe1();

    }
}
```

.

```
public class ShareMeTask {

    public void printMe2() {

        System.err.println("Spring 3 + Quartz 1.8.6 ~");


    }
    public void printMe1() {

        System.err.println("Spring Job execution");


    }

}
```

when time reached the above class is call and the method is run. but if admin want to configure cron at run time then how can will he configure it and please tell me the code for run time configuration and starting the scheduler.

i found there are some methods in shecduler for shutdown and start but how can i use these method at run time.

Answer (score 0):

*We can store the Cron-Expression to a properties fil to configure it dynamically, so you can modify when ever you need without touching the application code and repacking.*

Step(1): Create a File under as  /path/myFile.properties
cronExp.value=* 0/10 * * * ?

Step (2): Modify your spring xml as below:

```
<context:property-placeholder location= "file:/path/myFile.properties" />

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="${cronExp.value}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I know this. I want to configure scheduler at run time. e.g there will be a test box in ui. admin will put cron expression in that text box and press on save button, Depends on cron exp the schedule will do job.

Comment: To modify your job schedules at runtime, you can use of the available Quartz manager/GUIs.There are couple of them available such as MySchedule (https://code.google.com/p/myschedule/) or our product QuartzDesk (https://www.quartzdesk.com). Both products have online demos so you can check which one suits your needs.